# Как загрузить и выгрузить массив из бд?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redbeanphp

У меня в js коде формируется массив dataArr вида [0,4,5,4,7,4,5,27]

Как мне отправить его в бд, а потом забрать от туда в прежнем виде? 
Пытаюсь делать так:

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var lessonProgress = window.localStorage.getItem('dataArr'); //console.log = 0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
      var data = JSON.stringify(lessonProgress); //console.log = "0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../php/setData.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
      })
  });
```

**PHP (setData.php):**

```
<?php
require "db.php";

$data = $_POST;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  // Получаем id юзера чья сессия
  $userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
  // Загружаем данные об этом юзере
  $user = R::load( 'users', $userid );
  //Загружаем таблицу courses юзера
  $course = R::load( 'courses', $userid );

  $course->lessonProgress = json_encode($data); //В бд появляется {"\"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\"": ""}

  $user->ownCourseList[] = $course;
  R::store($user);
}
?>
```

---

Пытаюсь получить обратно

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: 'php/getData.php',
      data: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

**PHP (getData.php):**

```
<?php
require "db.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  // Получаем id users чья ссесия
  $userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
  // Загружаем данные об этом user
  $user = R::Load('users', $userid);
  //подгружаем дарные с таблицы Courses
  $course = R::load('courses', $userid);

  $lessonProgress = $course->lesson_progress;
}
echo json_decode($lessonProgress);

?>
```

В этом случае ответ от сервера:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) и [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php), т.е. при записи значения в БД - Вы должны сериализовать массив в строку, а при выборке из БД - десериализовать.

```php
$course->lessonProgress = json_encode($data);
```

---

Как альтернатива, если значения содержат только цифры, то можно просто произвести конкатенацию элементов массива в строку с помощью [join](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.join.php) и разделить обратно с помощью [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php):

```php
// "0,4,5,4,7,4,5,27"
$course->lessonProgress = join(",", $data);
```

Таким образом иногда поступают, когда значения (в Вашем случае номера уроков) являются первичными ключами какой-либо таблицы. После этого при выборе всех значений по их Id можно будет использовать [IN оператор](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

Comment: Спасибо, только я еще не правильно написал запись, там же массив передается значит нужно писать просто $data: `$course->lessonProgress = json_encode($data);`

Comment: @КириллМиронов я думаю, что в любом случае смысл должен быть понятен.

Comment: главное чтобы поиск в БД по этому массиву не понадобился

Comment: @XelaNimed Извините за беспокойство, я тут пытаюсь получить массив с базы с помощью `json_decode()` но в ответ от php получаю **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data** , а если без `json_decode()` получать, ответ приходит в формате json и в js отображается как `[object Object]`

Comment: @КириллМиронов посмотрите в БД что и как у Вас сохраняется. Вполне возможно, что проблема с экранированием спец.символов.

Comment: @XelaNimed в бд выглядит вот так **{"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,": ""}** в консоле **Полезная нагрузка ответа: {"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,": ""}** и JSON: **0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:** если не использовать `json_decode()`

Comment: @КириллМиронов а как выглядит массив, который Вы сериализируете? Посмотрите на него с помощью var_dump...

Comment: @XelaNimed `string(25) "{"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,": ""}"`

Comment: @XelaNimed вот так с json_decode() `object(stdClass)#21 (1) {
  ["0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: @КириллМиронов получается, что Вы сериализируете не массив, а строку. Проверяйте JS скрипт на стороне клиента, т.к. выглядит так, как-будто там какая-то ошибка.

Comment: @КириллМиронов когда Вы выводите содержимое ячейки таблицы непосредственно в переменныю JS, то JSON из БД становится обычным объектом JS, а если Вам необходимо получить массив на стороне сервера, то нужно десериализовать строку из БД в массив. И как-то странно у Вас массив выглядит... Может быть ключ и значение должны быть поменяны местами?